# Incorrect syntax near '=' in sql server 2005. Error in case statement in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to use case statement in where clause but getting error in the query below.

```
where 
 (r.WeekId=@WeekId or @WeekId is null) and
 (ShiftId=@ShiftId or @ShiftId is null)
 and (placeid=@PlaceId or @PlaceId is null)
 and (r.StatusId=3)
 AND     
CASE WHEN @day = 1 THEN ((firstday=@time and (allocateddays is null or NOT (AllocatedDays  LIKE '%1%')))) 
 WHEN @day = 2 THEN ((secondday=@time and (allocateddays is null or NOT (AllocatedDays LIKE '%2%'))))  
 WHEN @day = 3 THEN ((thirdday=@time  and (allocateddays is null or NOT (AllocatedDays LIKE '%3%')))) 
 ELSE AND (1 = 1) 
END
```

I am getting error at Case statement at line  `CASE WHEN @day = 1`. What is going wrong with my query. Please help.

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL can only return values - not entire expressions/code blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CASE` should be rewritten as an `OR` chain each of which uses `@day = n` for one of its conditions, owing to the fact that it `CASE` is expceted to return a value. It cannot execute conditionally in a `WHERE` clause.

If the condition like `@day = 1` returns `TRUE`, it is used as a boolean `AND` with the rest of the statement. Each of these is chained via `OR` to the previous.

```
where 
 (r.WeekId=@WeekId or @WeekId is null) and
 (ShiftId=@ShiftId or @ShiftId is null)
 and (placeid=@PlaceId or @PlaceId is null)
 and (r.StatusId=3)
 /* I *think* I have the () groups correct here... There's an unnecessary double (()) around firstday|secondday|thirddad */
 AND (
   (@day = 1 AND ((firstday=@time and (allocateddays is null or NOT (AllocatedDays  LIKE '%1%')))))
   OR (@day = 2 AND ((secondday=@time and (allocateddays is null or NOT (AllocatedDays LIKE '%2%')))))
   OR (@day = 3 AND ((thirdday=@time  and (allocateddays is null or NOT (AllocatedDays LIKE '%3%')))))
   /* Not certain if this is necessary in your case, as a catch-all to replace your ELSE */
   OR (@day NOT IN (1,2,3) AND 1=1) 
 )
```

Comment: Thanks. It perfectly working for me and clearing the concept. Thanks for the elaboration

Answer (score 1):

In a `WHERE` clause, the `CASE` statement can be used only to specify alternative values for a comparison like this:

```
where @day = 
    case @SomeCondition
        when 1 then @Sunday
        when 2 then @Monday
        ...
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have `ELSE AND...` no compiler will deal with that (except languages like Fortran).

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's wrong is that your CASE statements in the where clause are assigning values. For example when you do `firstdaay=@time`. You can't do that. You can only put expressions in the where clause that evaluate to `true` or `false`, nothing more. As a result, your whole where clause is wrong and frankly, doesn't make much sense to me.

Those conditions in the `where` clause seem to belong more to the `select` clause:

```
select ... 
case when @day=1  and (allocateddays is null or NOT (AllocatedDays  LIKE '%1%') then firstday=@time else null end as first_day,
case when @day=2 and (allocateddays is null or NOT (AllocatedDays LIKE '%2%') then secondday=@time else null end as second_day

from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The line:
ELSE AND (1 = 1) 
looks mighty suspicious.
Take that out and try.

Comment: Its a dummy conditional statement. it is not causing any problem